Scalar complex holomorphic function - same derivative as scalar real function?
My question is about the derivative of holomorphic complex functions.
Assume there is a function $f(x) := \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , and a function $f(z) := \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Further assume that both functions have a "counterpart", both in the complex and real domain (e.g. $\sin(x)$, $e^x$, $|.|$ or polynomials).
When $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ can we then conclude that $f'(x) = f'(z)$?
From my understanding the second Wirtinger derivative must be zero for any holomorphic function $f(z)$.
$$\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial z*} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial a}+i\frac{\partial f(z)}{\partial b}\right) = 0$$
Which somehow leads me to believe that $\frac{\partial f(z_0)}{\partial z} = f'(x_0)$ assuming $x_0 = z_0$. However, as this is only an "Intuition" from my side, and I am by no means a professional Mathematician. Maybe one of you can construct a counterexample to my observation.

It could happen that the real derivative exists but the complex derivative does not exist.  However, in the question it is assumed that the complex derivative exists.

To amend @GEdgar's comment, if you keep studying complex analysis you'll learn the very surprising theorem that if you start with a differentiable function on $\mathbb R$, then there are infinitely many ways to extend that to a function on $\mathbb C$, but at most one of them will be holomorphic.

That's indeed very interesting! Thanks for sharing.

Differentiability in $\mathbb{C}$ is a much stronger condition than differentiability in $\mathbb{R}$ (because there are more "paths of approach" for evaluating the limit of the difference quotient).
In particular (regarding $\mathbb{R}$ as $\{z\in\mathbb{C} : \operatorname{Im}(z) = 0\}$), if $f$ is differentiable as a function $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, then it is differentiable as a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and necessarily $f|_{\mathbb{R}}'(x) = f'(x)$.

To be fair, with your (and @brunob) reasoning it seems kind of obvious.
It was also a bit unclear to me that the holomorphic property and the differentiability are directly related. But everything is clear now - thank you :)
Relation of holomorphic property and differentiability.

I'll temporarily denote the real derivative as $f'_\mathbb{R}$ and the complex derivative as $f'_\mathbb{C}$.
Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, and assume that $f$ is real-analytic on a neighbourhood of $x_0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, so that it is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ in $\mathbb{C}$.
Then, pretty much by definition, we have:
$$f'_\mathbb{C}(x_0) = \lim_{h \to 0 \atop h \in \mathbb{C}} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0 \atop h \in \mathbb{R}} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} = f'_\mathbb{R}(x_0)$$

So I guess you mean $f'_{\mathbb{R}}(x_0)$ at the end

@MPW Thanks for having noticed the typo!
